# ERROR: Could not build wheels for realcugan-ncnn-vulkan-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python-3.x, installation, module

I'm trying to install module realcugan-ncnn-vulkan-python, but getting an error:

```
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '-S', '/private/var/folders/p9/mx7w4h2149vdglfr2c0ddmpm0000gn/T/pip-install-p6r_9mxi/realcugan-ncnn-vulkan-python_71a0be6d527745c59fa316681cfad201/realcugan_ncnn_vulkan_python', '-B', '/private/var/folders/p9/mx7w4h2149vdglfr2c0ddmpm0000gn/T/pip-install-p6r_9mxi/realcugan-ncnn-vulkan-python_71a0be6d527745c59fa316681cfad201/build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39_realcugan-ncnn-vulkan-python', '-GNinja', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/private/var/folders/p9/mx7w4h2149vdglfr2c0ddmpm0000gn/T/pip-install-p6r_9mxi/realcugan-ncnn-vulkan-python_71a0be6d527745c59fa316681cfad201/build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/realcugan_ncnn_vulkan_python', '-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/private/var/folders/p9/mx7w4h2149vdglfr2c0ddmpm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-vfonxjmm/overlay/bin/ninja', '-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF', '-DCALL_FROM_SETUP_PY:BOOL=ON']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for realcugan-ncnn-vulkan-python
Failed to build realcugan-ncnn-vulkan-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for realcugan-ncnn-vulkan-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

anybody knows what's going wrong?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.